# Lose context of this when youtube constructor method is called

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have created a youtube player using the youtube iframe api, I am listening for the `ENDED` event but I've realised that I lose the reference to `this` which becomes the window but I'm really unsure how to resolve this. I've tried binding `this` to the contsructor etc but with no joy whatesoever so could really do with you guys help.

**JS**

```
startPlayer: function (videoId) {

            var instance = this;
            console.log('startPlayer', instance);

            if( instance.flags.isPlaying ) {

                instance.selectors.playerCtn.empty();

                instance.flags.isPlaying = false;

            }

            instance.selectors.playerCtn.append('<div id="player"></div>');

            instance.player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: videoId,
                events: {
                    'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

            instance.flags.isPlaying = true;
        },

onPlayerStateChange: function (event) {
            console.log('onPlayerStateChange');

            var instance = this;

            console.log(instance); //undefined??

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                console.log('PLAYING...');
            }

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                console.log('PAUSED...');
            }

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

                console.log('what is this', instance);

                // if instance.counter === instance.playlist
                if (instance.counter === instance.playlist) {
                    console.log('you\'ve come to the end of your playlist');
                    // Display message or go back to first?
                    return;
                }

                // Increase the counter
                instance.counter++
                // Set the new current element
                instance.current = instance.selectors.listItems[instance.counter];

                console.log(instance.counter);
                console.log(instance.current);

                // Get the new current element data-id
                var videoId = instance.current.attr('data-id');

                // Start the player
                startPlayer(videoId);
            }

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
                console.log('BUFFERING...');
            }
        }
```

**Test page** http://go.shr.lc/1lh2dmu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events: {
    'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this),
    'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)
}
```

Besides, why `var instance = this;`? `this` is quite shorter to type and you aren't using `instance` in any closure.

Comment: I added .bind to everywhere except the actual events! Thanks for this!

Comment: @styler Event handlers are usually the only place you need `bind`, unless you are passing function references around for another purpose and need them to stay bound.

Comment: Yeah I've no need to be using instance so will swap out for this!

Comment: @styler You will sometimes see people alias `this` to a local variable so that it results in better compressed code, however I believe that after gzip compression it doesn't change anything and even if it does, then I would delegate that task to the minimizer itself.

Comment: Yeah I sometimes get confused about what I should actually be doing with this, should I alias it or should I just straight up use it based on reading others code etc, I totally get what you're saying though. thanks for the explanation!